# C++ - why implement op+ in terms of op+= and not the other way around?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, code-reuse

Why is this implementation:

```
T& T::operator+=(const T&) {
  // ... implementation ...
  return *this;
}

T operator+(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
  T temp(lhs);
  return temp += rhs;
}
```

more common than this one:

```
T& T::operator+=(const T& rhs) {
  *this = *this + rhs;
  return *this;
}

T operator+(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
  // ... implementation ...
  return some_result;
}
```

Is there any reason at all, or is it just a random coincidence that I've seen people implement it this way multiple times in the literature that I read, and never the other way around?

Comment: Test the second one, and you'll find it doesn't work. Exactly how it doesn't work will depend on what goes on in `// ... implementation ...`, but it's not going to work. Most likely, `return *this + rhs;` will completely fail to do anything to `this`.

Comment: @user2357112: Does my answer explain the problem you spotted, or is there another?

Comment: Please don't change post by seeing answers. It will make answers useless

Comment: @user2357112 The answer below did. It's late; I'm not thinking clear. Sorry about the mistake.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, your answer seems to address everything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`operator+` has to create a new object to hold the result.  `operator+=` doesn't need a new object.

If you write `operator+=` in terms of `operator+`, then you end up paying for an extra new object creation, an assignment (or swap), and a destruction, all of which you didn't need.

Besides that, on many processors, the hardware has direct support for `+=` and similar operations where the result is stored back to one of the input registers, and none for storing to a third register (like `+`).

BTW, there's a mistake in your (original, now edited) code that hides part of the extra work.  You actually need:

```
T& T::operator+=( const T& rhs )
{
    *this = *this + rhs; // creation of temporary, move assignment, and destruction of temporary
    return *this;
}
```

Even worse, your (again original, now edited) suggested implementation of `operator+` fails to return the new object properly, it returns a dangling reference instead.  That's undefined behavior.

---

For those interested, the first `operator+` implementation can be improved even further by using pass-by-value:

```
T operator+( T lhs, const T& rhs )
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Now if the left hand operand of `operator+` is a temporary, the move constructor will be used, avoiding a copy.  Although with NRVO, there probably isn't much advantage in the resulting code either way.

Comment: But don't we create a new object anyways? We create T temp in one case, and we create some_result in the other. Doesn't it come down to the same thing?

Comment: @EnnMichael: There's nothing in the direct implementation of `operator+=` that creates a new object.  Thinking about `std::complex<T>`, it would look like `T& std::complex<T>::operator+=(const std::complex<S>& rhs) { re += rhs.re; im += rhs.im; return *this; }`  No new temporaries are created, every statement maps exactly to a single CPU instruction (on common architectures)

Comment: @EnnMichael: If you're asking whether both variations of `operator+` (not `+=`) create a temp object, yes, that's necessary.  It's also what my answer starts out saying.  The problem with your suggested approach is incredibly inefficient `+=`.

Comment: Thanks alot! I get it now. In my version, efficiently operator+ stays the same, except my operator+= is just worse, because it does an extra copy operation.

Comment: @Yakk parameters shouldn't be eligible in the first place.

Comment: @Yakk: Yes, I agree with that.

Comment: That + with a lhs copy is actually awesome: examine `auto x=a+b+c+d+e;`, and compare to `const&` lhs + in the case of cheap-move code: one "real" object created and then just moves with lhs-as-copy, but tonnes of "real" temporaries created and discarded with lhs-as `const&`.

Comment: Why say "isn't much advantage in the resulting code either way."?

Comment: @Yakk: Because in the version with `const T&` argument, NRVO can be in effect, making a copy directly into the return value.  One copy instead of two moves -- depending on the type, either one could be faster.

Comment: @Yakk RVO doesn't apply to `lhs` though. We still would move-construct four objects.

Comment: Ok, for n-arg `auto _=a+...+z;` we get 1 copy n-1 move, vs n-1 copy.  So ya, if move is costly, the lhs as value is bad.  In in my experience, either move is near-free or same as copy, so at least the decision is easy.  Unless you are writing very generic code, you won't have to do both `T const&` and `T&&` overloads (which gives you best of both worlds: 1 copy n-2 moves)

Comment: @Yakk: By my count, it is "1 copy + 2*n-1 moves" vs "n-1 copies"  The all-copy version (with `const T&` parameter) is better when move and copy are similar in cost.

Comment: @ben return value can be elided into argument of next `+`, no?  So 1 move (from parameter into return value) per `+`